# How to check if a datarow exists by row index?

Tags: c#

which is the correct procedure to find a datarow exists in datatable?

Running the below code is giving the following error:

> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 99.

```
int myRowNumber = 99;
if (myDatatable.Rows[myRowNumber] == null)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("row does not exists");
      return;
     }
```

Comment: well first you need to check if `myRowNumber < myDataTable.Rows.Length` otherwise you will get that out of bounds error

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Nice one

Answer (score 2):

How about using an `if` condition?

```
if(myDatatable.Rows.Count <= myRowNumber)
{
    MessageBox.Show("row does not exists");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("row exists");
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the lower bound `index >=  0`

Answer (score 2):

```
int myRowNumber = 99;
if (!myDatatable.HasRowAt(myRowNumber))
{
    MessageBox.Show("row does not exists");
}
```

You can create your own extension method for the data table and reuse it later in your code.

```
public static bool HasRowAt(this DataTable dt, int index)
{
    return (dt.Rows.Count <= index) And (index >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a try on this?

```
 if (myDatatable.Rows.Count > myRowNumber - 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("row exists");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("row does not exists");
                return;

            }
```

Comment: Don't forget the lower bound `index >=  0`